# GSON Structure Difficulties

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm a little unsure with regards to creating a structure for my JSON file to easily deserialise it. The file is a bible translation from [GitHub](https://github.com/thiagobodruk/bible/blob/master/json/en_kjv.json).

#### Existing Code:

```
JSONArray bibleData = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset("KJV"));

bibleBooks = new JSONArray[66];
Integer[] bibleChapters = new Integer[66];

int maxChapters = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < BIBLE.length; i++) {

    bibleBooks[i]  = (JSONArray) bibleData.getJSONObject(i).get("chapters");
    bibleChapters[i] = bibleBooks[i].length();

    if (bibleChapters[i] > maxChapters) {

        maxChapters = bibleChapters[i];

    }

}
//Get individual chapters in JSON array

JSONObject[][] chapters = new JSONObject[BIBLE.length][maxChapters];

int iVal = 0;
int i1Val = 0;

try {

    for (int i = 0; i < BIBLE.length;i++) {

        iVal = i;

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < maxChapters; i1++) {

            i1Val = i1;

            // Ensure don't start to access non-existent chapters
            if (i1 < bibleChapters[i]) {

                chapters[i][i1] = bibleBooks[i].getJSONObject(i1);
                

            } else {

                break;

            }

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("JSON Read Error","i = " + Integer.toString(iVal) + ", i1 = " + Integer.toString(i1Val));

}
```

It works up to a point, but I'm stuck after accessing the chapters JSONArray and creating an object for each item. I can't figure out how to access the "1" (chapter #) and subsequently the verses.

Getting chapters[0][0] returns the correct section, but looking like this:

```
{"1":{"1":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.","2":"And the.....
```

I tried extracting a JSONObject from this, but it fails when I enter chapter[i][i1].get("1") or chapter[i][i1].get(0).

#### GSON

I've update my GSON, but it returns the following:

```
GSON Output: [[[abbrev=gn, book=Genesis, chapters=[[null], [null], [null], [null], [null],
```

The correct number of [null] chapters appear for every book, however they're clearly not reading properly and I'm not sure what I did wrong. Also, is it just me or should there only be "[[" at the start, instead of "[[["??? It's an array of books, not an array of arrays of books.

```
public class Book {
    private String abbrev;
    private String book;
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }

    public void setAbbrev(String abbrev) {
        this.abbrev = abbrev;
    }

    public String getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(String book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public List<Chapter> getChapters() {
        return chapters;
    }

    public void setChapters(List<Chapter> chapters) {
        this.chapters = chapters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[abbrev=" + abbrev + ", book=" + book + ", chapters=" + chapters + "]";
    }

}

/**
 * Chapter POJO
 */
public class Chapter {
    private List<Verses> verses;

    public List<Verses> getVerses() {
        return verses;
    }

    public void setVerses(List<Verses> verses) {
        this.verses = verses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + verses + "]";
    }

}

/**
 * Verse POJO
 */
public class Verses {
    private List<Verse> verse;

    public List<Verse> getVerse() {
        return verse;
    }

    public void setVerse(List<Verse> verse) {
        this.verse = verse;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + verse + "]";
    }

}

public class Verse {

    private String verseNum;
    private String verseContent;

    public String getverseNum() {
        return verseNum;
    }

    public void setverseNum(String verseNum) {
        this.verseNum = verseNum;
    }

    public String verseContent() {
        return verseContent;
    }

    public void verseContent(String verseContent) {
        this.verseContent = verseContent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{"+ verseNum + ", " + verseContent + "}";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

GSON is a very powerful library and it can easily solve this type of JSON deserializing issues. The only catch is, you need to have correct POJOs in place.

Looking at your JSON structure, it seems that you are having a `List` of `Book` items. So let's start creating appropriate POJOs.

**STEP 1:** Create a POJO class called `Book` which has `abbrev`, `book` and `chapters` as it's members:

```
public class Book {
    private String abbrev;
    private String book;
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }

    public void setAbbrev(String abbrev) {
        this.abbrev = abbrev;
    }

    public String getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(String book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public List<Chapter> getChapters() {
        return chapters;
    }

    public void setChapters(List<Chapter> chapters) {
        this.chapters = chapters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [abbrev=" + abbrev + ", book=" + book + ", chapters=" + chapters + "]";
    }

}
```

**STEP 2:** Create a POJO class called `Chapter`. If you look closely, each `Chapter` has 3 `Verse`. So you also need a `Verse` POJO class which has 2 `String` members. Let's call them as `verseContent1` and `verseContent2`. So your `Chapter` and `Verse` class should look like:

```
/**
 * 
 * Chapter POJO
 *
 */
public class Chapter {
    @SerializedName("1")
    private Verse verse1;
    @SerializedName("2")
    private Verse verse2;
    @SerializedName("3")
    private Verse verse3;

    public Verse getVerse1() {
        return verse1;
    }

    public void setVerse1(Verse verse1) {
        this.verse1 = verse1;
    }

    public Verse getVerse2() {
        return verse2;
    }

    public void setVerse2(Verse verse2) {
        this.verse2 = verse2;
    }

    public Verse getVerse3() {
        return verse3;
    }

    public void setVerse3(Verse verse3) {
        this.verse3 = verse3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Chapter [verse1=" + verse1 + ", verse2=" + verse2 + ", verse3=" + verse3 + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
/**
 * 
 * Verse POJO
 *
 */
public class Verse {
    @SerializedName("1")
    private String verseContent1;
    @SerializedName("2")
    private String verseContent2;

    public String getVerseContent1() {
        return verseContent1;
    }

    public void setVerseContent1(String verseContent1) {
        this.verseContent1 = verseContent1;
    }

    public String getVerseContent2() {
        return verseContent2;
    }

    public void setVerseContent2(String verseContent2) {
        this.verseContent2 = verseContent2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Verse [verseContent1=" + verseContent1 + ", verseContent2=" + verseContent2 + "]";
    }

}
```

Now, your platform is set. Your next approach is to use these POJOs to deserialize your JSON into `List<Book>` Object.

As your JSON starts as an array, in your client code, you need to create a `TypeToken` to get information of the enclosing objects at run-time. As `TypeToken` uses reflection at run-time, you can store the type of `List<Book>` in a `java.lang.reflect.Type` variable. Later you can use the same to get your deserialized object. Your code snippet should be like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

Type bookList = new TypeToken<List<Book>>(){}.getType();
//Get a List of Book
List<Book> bible = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFilePath), bookList);
```

Later you can iterate over this `List<Book>` to do your specific operations.
I hope this helps in your learning activity.

Comment: Ok, first of all, thanks for the comprehensive guide! This helps a lot with the principles. I am having a bit of difficulty customising it to my needs. As it turns out, the number of verses is variable (never 3) - I just displayed the first 3 to give you an idea of the structure.